# DD-WRT: Cannot access web interface

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I've just installed DD-WRT on an old router I had laying around. The router was working fine and web admin was accessible through 192.168.1.1. I just installed DD-WRT and the firmware was flashed successfully. I can now successfully connect to SSID ddwrt, but I am unable to access the router admin interface to change the default settings.

My device is a TP-Link TL-WR741ND v1.9, hardware version: WR741N v1 00000000. What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: The best thing to do is, when changes need to be made to the router's configuration, is to connect to the router via cable.
Once your configuration changes are done, restart the router.
Maybe is the admin interface not accessible over wi-fi by a setting?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. The web interface is not accessible, even when connected by cable.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Are you sure you are entering the correct IP address? Can you provide a screenshot maybe?

Comment: No, no error message, it just won't connect me... Until 'connection timed out'. Yes, I did, @Tim_Stewart, from the official website of DD-WRT. And to be fair, it is working, i am connected through this router right now, but I am not able to change the settings

Comment: I would be able to provide a screenshot but there is nothing to show... When I try connecting through the web admin page, it just won't connect. I was reading DD-WRT official website and they say the admin page IP will remain the same. How could I check if the IP changed somehow, ifconfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router firmware **should not** be downloaded from the [router database section.](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Firmware_FAQ#Where_do_I_download_firmware.3F)

This is from the FAQ section: "Where do I Download firmware?"
[image]
It would be nice if they gave people this warning **in the router database**.
(It's basically just used to see if your router is supported by DD-WRT firmware)

What you are describing is a bug in the firmware, it means the HTTP daemon isn't running. This is a common bug from images in the router database.

Here is what you should do:

- Go to  https://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/
- Download a new copy of the firmware for your router.
- use the command prompt via telnet or ssh, flash the new image onto the router
  (be patient, wait at least 5 mins for it to flash)
- If you are still having issues after re-flashing, follow the instructions at the section in the link above titled:
  "Why has http stopped working on my router after flashing DD-WRT?"

Let me know if you run into trouble.

Comment: Damn, failed to see this warning... Thanks Tim, gonna try it out right now and I'll let you know. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Someone elsewhere pointed out I had to refresh and renew my IP through the CLI. Then I was able to access the web interface through the standard 192.168.1.1. But you were partially right, the firmware was buggy as hell, and right now I am going to flash a new one (it was pretty late for me too, ended up sleeping). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Lol They always are from that section. 

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit old.
If you don't want to restart completely, you can just kill and restart the HTTP daemon.
Open `telnet` in the command line:

```
telnet 192.168.1.1       192.168.1.1 needs to be adapted to your real router IP
DD-WRT login: root       not 'admin' or anything else but always 'root'
Password: <your password>
```

After logging in:

```
kill `cat /tmp/var/run/httpd.pid` & httpd -n -p 80
```

This restarts the affected HTTP daemon.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do with the DD-WRT site, is to use the router database to lookup your router: as an example, [use this page](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/?model=R6300_v2)

There is a drop-down on the page listing the specific versions built for that router.  It is my understanding, that these versions have a change applicable to the router.  Loading a version outside of this list is also not a good idea.  This one lists builds for the v3.0 beta, but v3.0 has a lot of releases that are good.  v3.0 has been in a beta state for a long time (years), but is widely used.  40559 and later have had an issue with the internal web service reported (which provides the configuration pages).  I, personally, have not had any problems with builds prior to 40559

Comment: Wow, way to instruct someone to brick a router. "**Loading a version outside of this list is also not a good idea**" it's vice versa, loading firmware from that list is possible bricksville. Read the FAQ section guy...